# Generate JSON array with LKJSON in Delphi 7

Tags: json, delphi

I want to produce something like this:

```json
{
  "nrVendas": 2, 
  "totalVendas": 100.0, 
  "vendas": [ 
    {
      "nsuOrigem": "1",
      "data": "2014-03-14",
      "nrParcelas": 1,
      "valor": 50,
      "parcelas": [
        {
          "numero": 1,
          "valor": 50
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "nsuOrigem": "2",
      "data": "2014-03-14",
      "nrParcelas": 1,
      "valor": 50,
      "parcelas": [
        {
          "numero": 1,
          "valor": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying it this way:

```pascal
js3 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js3.Add('numero', '1');
js3.Add('valor', '50');

js32 :=  TlkJSONobject.Create;
js32.Add('numero', '1');
js32.Add('valor', '100');

js2 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js2.Add('nsuOrigem', '1');
js2.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
js2.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
js2.Add('valor', 50);
js2.Add('parcelas', js3);

js2.Add('nsuOrigem', '2');
js2.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
js2.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
js2.Add('valor', 50);
js2.Add('parcelas', js32);

js0 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js0.Add('numeroVendas', 2);
js0.Add('totalVendas', 100.0);
js0.Add('vendas', js2);

i := 0;
s := GenerateReadableText(js0, i);

Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
```

But I'm receiving this instead:

```json
{
  "numeroVendas": 2,
  "totalVendas": 100,
  "vendas": {
    "nsuOrigem": "1",
    "data": "2014-02-02",
    "nrParcelas": 1,
    "valor": 50,
    "parcelas": {
      "numero": "1",
      "valor": "50"
    },
    "nsuOrigem": "2",
    "data": "2014-02-02",
    "nrParcelas": 1,
    "valor": 50,
    "parcelas": {
      "numero": "1",
      "valor": "100"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I try to validade this JSON, but i received this error:

> SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'nsuOrigem' on line 13

I think I need to use an array on the fields inside `vendas`, but I searched in all of the documentation and more, but I can't find anything that can help me.

Comment: Well, you aren't attempting to create an array, so why would you expect one? Read the code again. Read the examples for array creation for this library. Don't make the classic mistake of trying to write your final code without first learning the library using simple examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating any arrays at all.  `vendas` and `parcelas` are both an array of objects, but you are creating them as through they are single objects instead.

You are also creating a few of the JSON values as strings instead of as numbers.

Use the `TlkJSONlist` class to create arrays, eg:

```
js4_1 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js4_1.Add('numero', 1);
js4_1.Add('valor', 50);

js4_2 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js4_2.Add('numero', 1);
js4_2.Add('valor', 100);

js3_1 := TlkSONlist.Create;
js3_1.Add(js4_1);

js3_2 := TlkSONlist.Create;
js3_2.Add(js4_2);

js2_1 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js2_1.Add('nsuOrigem', '1');
js2_1.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
js2_1.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
js2_1.Add('valor', 50);
js2_1.Add('parcelas', js3_1);

js2_2.Add('nsuOrigem', '2');
js2_2.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
js2_2.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
js2_2.Add('valor', 50);
js2_2.Add('parcelas', js3_2);

js1 := TlkJSONlist.Create;
js1.Add(js2_1);
js1.Add(js2_2);

js0 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js0.Add('numeroVendas', 2);
js0.Add('totalVendas', 100.0);
js0.Add('vendas', js1);

i := 0;
s := GenerateReadableText(js0, i);

Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
```

But please, give your variables more meaningful names!  And change the order of your class constructions, it will make the code much easier to read and follow, eg:

```
root := TlkJSONobject.Create;
root.Add('numeroVendas', 2);
root.Add('totalVendas', 100.0);
vendas := TlkJSONList.Create;
root.Add('vendas', vendas);

venda := TlkJSONobject.Create;
vendas.Add(venda);
venda.Add('nsuOrigem', '1');
venda.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
venda.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
venda.Add('valor', 50);
parcelas := TlkJSONlist.Create;
venda.Add('parcelas', parcelas);

parcela := TlkJSONobject.Create;
parcelas.Add(parcela);
parcela.Add('numero', 1);
parcela.Add('valor', 50);

venda := TlkJSONobject.Create;
vendas.Add(venda);
venda.Add('nsuOrigem', '1');
venda.Add('data', '2014-02-02');
venda.Add('nrParcelas', 1);
venda.Add('valor', 50);
parcelas := TlkJSONlist.Create;
venda.Add('parcelas', parcelas);

parcela := TlkJSONobject.Create;
parcelas.Add(parcela);
parcela.Add('numero', 1);
parcela.Add('valor', 100);

i := 0;
s := GenerateReadableText(root, i);

Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
```